# Find the most common property of a model using iterative approach and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a following Model class:

```
public class Student
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Major { get; set; }
     public int Age { get; set; }
}


public string GetPrimaryMajor(List<Student> students)
{ 
     ... 
}
```

How can I implement the method `GetPrimaryMajor()` to determine the most commonly occurring `Major` in the `students` parameter using iterative and LINQ approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is clearly homework, I'll give you the easy/easier one and you can figure out the iterative approach from there.

```
public string GetPrimaryMajor(List<Student> students)
{    
    var mostCommonMajor = students
                              .GroupBy(m => m.Major)
                              .OrderByDescending(gp => gp.Count())
                              .FirstOrDefault()? // null-conditional operator
                              .Select(s => s.Major)
                              .FirstOrDefault();

    return mostCommonMajor;
}
```

For the iterative approach, consider the following pseudo-code as one potential simple, iterative (potentially poor performing) algorithm:

```
// Iterate students
// Track count of each major
// Keep track of most commonly occurring major by comparing count of 
// currently iterated value vs current most commonly occurring value count
// Return most commonly occurred major at end of loop.
```

Answer (score 2):

An iterative approach using [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx). A lot of comments to explain it step inside.

The second half is probably especially inefficient, finding the max is certainly much easier using LINQ. But @DavidL has already provided an excellent LINQ answer, so thought I'd stay say and use no LINQ whatsoever.

```
public string GetPrimaryMajor(List<Student> students)
{
    //Create a dictionary of string and int. These are our major names and and the count of students in thaat major respectively
    Dictionary<string, int> MajorCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    //Iterate through all students
    foreach (Student stu in students)
    {
        //Check if we have already found a student with that major
        if (MajorCounts.ContainsKey(stu.Major))
        {
            //If yes add one to the count of students with that major
            MajorCounts[stu.Major]++;
        }
        else
        {
            //If no create a key for that major, start at one to count the student we just found
            MajorCounts.Add(stu.Major, 1);
        }
    }

    //Now that we have our majors and number of students in each major we need to find the highest one

    //Our first one starts as our highest found
    string HighestMajor = MajorCounts.First().Key;
    //iterate through all the majors
    for (int i = 0; i < MajorCounts.Count(); i++)
    {
        //If we find a major with higher student count, replace our current highest major
        if (MajorCounts.ElementAt(i).Value > MajorCounts[HighestMajor])
        {
            HighestMajor = MajorCounts.ElementAt(i).Key;
        }
    }
    //Return the highet major
    return HighestMajor;
}
```

Basically populate a dictionary by using the `Major` as a string key, and increasing the value `int` by one each time a Student has that major. Then a basic iteration through the dictionary to find the key with the highest value.